# UIKeyboardAppearance broken: showing both styles at once

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikeyboard, uiappearance

I have a `UITextView` with the keyboard appearance set to dark. But once I present and then dismiss a `UINavigationController` I get a keyboard like this:

[image]

Now I'm not sure what to do to get this back to normal? Once I dismiss the keyboard and show it again it is back to normal, however this is not acceptable.

I'm assuming this is an Apple bug, but does anybody know a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out how to get around this bug. You simply have to dismiss the keyboard before you present the view controller. Like so:

```
[self.textView resignFirstResponder];
```

I'm not sure what causes this bug, but just case anyone else is having this problem, that's what I'm doing to fix it.